# Inserting DATE to MYSQL database.. Posting values from Android to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have a date value in format dd-mm-yyyy and I want to insert DATE or DATETIME value to mysql database, but the insert is always 0000-00-00

Already tried this but doesnt work for me.

```
$dateOne = $_POST['dateOne'];
$dateTwo = $_POST['dateTwo'];

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateOne));
$ts = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateTwo));
```

PHP part

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$myname= $_POST['myName'];
$dateOne = $_POST['dateOne'];
$dateTwo = $_POST['dateTwo'];

$timestampa = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateOne));
$tsa = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateTwo));

$sql = "INSERT INTO hires_bp (suraduju_od, suraduju_do,  id_band, id_producer) VALUES ($timestampa, $tsa, (SELECT id FROM band WHERE band_name = '$myname'), (SELECT id FROM producer WHERE producer_name = '$name'))";
```

Android / Java part - for dateTwo.. dateOne is the same

```
mCurrentDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
int year = mCurrentDate.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
int month = mCurrentDate.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
int day = mCurrentDate.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(Calendar.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
mDateTwoEditText.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year);
mCurrentDate.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
}
}, year, month, day);
mDatePicker.show();
}
```

Getting strings from edittext and posting parameters.. using volley.. here's just a smal part of code cause I think there isn't a problem here.. other data inserts correct..

```
final String dateOne = mDateOneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
final String dateTwo = mDateOneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
```

......

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("myName", majName);
                params.put("dateOne", dateOne);
                params.put("dateTwo", dateTwo);

                return params;
            }
```

I expected the insert would be actual picked date, but instead the insert is 0000-00-00.. other data is inserted correctly..

Comment: have you checked if the post variable contains the expected datestring?

Answer (score 0):

MySql default date format is [YYYY-MM-DD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Change date format from dd-mm-yyyy to **yyyy-mm-dd** it will work

Comment: so then I wont need this line: $timestampa = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateOne));  ?

Comment: @DinoKrivičić Checks dates are converted correctly in php side. Debug your code.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think your concern should be posted as a comment. The edit fixed whatever could be fixed in that answer, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

$sql = "INSERT INTO hires_bp (suraduju_od, suraduju_do,  id_band, id_producer) VALUES ($timestampa, $tsa, (SELECT id FROM band WHERE band_name = '$myname'), (SELECT id FROM producer WHERE producer_name = '$name'))";

'' missing --> $timestampa and $tsa..

'$timestampa' and '$tsa'

Answer (score 0):

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

We have data types in both Java and SQL, so use them. Thinking and working in mere strings is awkward, error-prone, and leaves you vulnerable to [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

In contrast, working with appropriate data types makes your code [simpler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegance) and more [self-documenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting_code), provides [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety), and ensures [valid values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation).

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

## *java.time*

Use `LocalDate` for a date-only value. This class would be appropriate for working with database columns of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `DATE`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2019 , 1 , 23 ) ;  // January 23, 2019.
```

Using JDBC 4.2 and later, pass to the database. Use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to prevent SQL-Injection attacks.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

## Parse strings

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;
```

## Generate strings

Generate strings for display to user. Either automatically localize with `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`, or generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard YYYY-MM-DD format.
```

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;   // Or Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( l )
;
String output = ld.format( f );
```

> mercredi 23 janvier 2019

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern & legacy) and in standard SQL.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).